# Reactive objects, like in vue

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming

I like the reactivity of vue and created a function that makes `Object`'s reactive. Just like in vue 3  [`.reactive`](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/reactivity/src/reactive.ts)

I wonder if my approach is ok or i have made a fundamental mistake:

```js
const item = {
    foo: "bar",
    bool: true,
    arr: ["hello", {
        world: "Its nice here",
        enabled: true,
    }, Date.now(), Buffer.from("Hello")],
    nested: {
        buff: Buffer.from("World"),
        seems: {
            ts: Date.now(),
            like: {
                arr: ["foo", true, Symbol("bar")],
                it: {
                    is: {
                        so: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * @function reactive
 * Returns the given object wrapped in a proxy object.<br />
 * Get/set & apply calls to the object are intercepted and additional callbacks called.
 * 
 * @param {Object|Array} obj Instace of `Object`. Anything that can in js be called "Object"
 * @param {Function} getter Same as proxy `get()`
 * @param {Function} setter Same as proxy `set()`
 * @param {Function} apply Same as proxy `apply()`
 * 
 * @returns {Proxy} Wrapped given <obj> Object.
 * 
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply
 */
function reactive(obj, getter = () => {
    // dummy
    // args: target, prop, receiver
}, setter = () => {
    // dummy
    // args: target, prop, value
}, apply = () => {
    // dummy
    // args: target, scope, args
}) {

    for (let prop in obj) {
        if (obj[prop] instanceof Object && !obj[prop] instanceof Buffer) {
            console.log("Wrapp object", obj[prop])
            obj[prop] = reactive(obj[prop], getter, setter, apply);
        }
    }

    return new Proxy(obj, {
        set(target, prop, value) {

            //console.log("setter();", "obj: ", obj, "prop:", prop, "value: ", value);
            setter(target, prop, value);
            target[prop] = value;

        },
        get(target, prop, receiver) {

            //console.log("getter();", "target: ", target, "prop:", prop);
            getter(target, prop, receiver);
            return target[prop];

        },
        apply(target, scope, args) {

            //console.log("apply: target: ", target, "scope:", scope, "args: ", args);
            apply(target, scope, args);
            return target.apply(scope, args);

        }
    });

}



const proxy = reactive(item, (target, prop, receiver) => {
    // getter
    console.log("getter();", "target: ", target, "prop:", prop);
}, (target, prop, value) => {
    // setter
    console.log("setter();", "target: ", target, "prop:", prop, "value: ", value);
}, (target, scope, args) => {
    // apply
    console.log("apply: target: ", target, "scope:", scope, "args: ", args);
});

//proxy.nested.seems.like.it.is.so = false
//console.log(proxy.nested.seems.like.it.is.so);


//console.log(proxy.arr[1].world)
//proxy.arr[1].world = "changed text";
//proxy.arr[0] = false;

console.log(proxy)
```

The function works as expected and i have not found any problems.